# How to change table data in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-rc

I have randomly generated table. Currently I am able to get table cell data using `selenium.getTable(XPath)` but I am not able change that value. My functions are :

```
    public static String getGridCellValue(Selenium selenium, String strGridId, int nRowIndex, int nCellIndex)
{
    String strXPath = "//div[@id='"+strGridId+"']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/table."+(nRowIndex + 1)+"."+(nCellIndex);
    return selenium.getTable(strXPath);
}
```

But I am not able to write set method as :

```
    public static void setGridCellValue(Selenium selenium, String strGridId, int nRowIndex, int nCellIndex, String strValue)
{

    String strXPath = "//div[@id='"+strGridId+"']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/table."+(nRowIndex + 1)+"."+(nCellIndex);
    selenium.type(strXPath, strValue);
}
```

It is saying

> com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Element //div[@id='gridPShipsRel']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/table.1.5 not found

Does anyone know how to set table value in selenium ?

Comment: Would be helpful if you could mention which Selenium are you using, because you have tagged `Selenium WebDriver` but your code suggests you are using `Selenium RC`

Comment: `WebDriver` does not have a `getTable` function. If you are indeed using `WebDriver` then use that and not `Selenium` object.

Comment: `com.thoughtworks.selenium.` means Selenium RC

Comment: It's evident it's Selenium RC, so I've tagged the question with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how `strXPath = "//div[@id='"+strGridId+"']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/table."+(nRowIndex + 1)+"."+(nCellIndex)` will retrieve cell. Add some HTML or

You can following method, this will update the cell value

```
public String updateCell(By identifier, int romNumber, int columnNumber, String value) 
{
   WebElement table = driver.findElement(identifier);
   List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.xpath("tbody/tr"));
   List<WebElement> cells = rows.get(romNumber).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
   WebElement desiredCell = cells.get(columnNumber);
   desiredCell.setText(value);
}
```

**EDIT :**
By Looking at your imports `com.thoughtworks.selenium.` I can say that you are using Selenium RC. My solution is webdriver based

Answer (score 0):

For your set method try to give xpath this way:

```
strXpath = "//div[@id='"+strGridId+"']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr["+(nRowIndex + 1)+"]/td[" +(nCellIndex)+"]"
```